# How can I remove OLD history from Google Chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, history

I'm working on a laptop with a modest hard drive, and 500MB is taken up with Google Chrome "History Index" and "Thumbnails" files.  Some of these files are a year old.  Chrome offers me the option to remove *recent* history, but I want the opposite: I want to remove *old* history.  (Ideally I would remove the least recently used history information, but  I don't expect to be able to do that.)

Anyone have any ideas?  I'm running the standard Debian `google-chrome-beta` package.

Comment: Chrome now has built in support for clearing history, cookies, and other data, so this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: @nhinkle: please cite version number or page of google documentation.  chrome has had "support" for some time, but the support as of chrome 11 (current stable version) allows only to delete *recent* history, not *old* history

Comment: that's fair; I've re-opened the question. My apologies for not understanding it properly.

Comment: @NormanRamsey, Chrome **automatically** remove history older than 90 days. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shameful to Google, there is [no way yet](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=59de9a3b5737283e&hl=en).

Besides that, all the Chrome databases are just sqlite3 files, and you can use sqlite3 to purge unneeded entries. First, install the `sqlite3` client (`sudo apt-get install sqlite3`), and then go to Chrome config (should be `.config/chrome/Default`).

Here is an SQL snippet which purges old URLs from history (works on databases `History`, `Archived History`):

```
delete from urls where last_visit_time <= (strftime('%s',(select 
   max(last_visit_time)/10000000 from urls),'unixepoch','-1 days')*10000000);
```

Here is another one which will probably work on `Thumbnails` database:

```
attach database 'History' as history;
delete from thumbnails where last_updated <= (strftime('%s',(select 
   max(last_visit_time)/10000000 from history.urls),'unixepoch','-1 days')
   *10000000);
```

This will probably work on `History Index`-es:

```
attach database 'History' as history;
delete from info i, pages_content pc where i.time <= (strftime('%s',(select
   max(last_visit_time)/10000000 from history.urls),'unixepoch','-1 days')*
   10000000) and i.rowid = pc.rowid;
```

Of course you should backup all the databases, because you may have different version of Chrome, or I may accidentally miss a symbol, etc.

As Chrome stores its times in some weird format based on UNIX Epoch (but multiplied by 10^7 and shifted to the future), system functions returning date cannot be used; the date of last page opening is used instead.

You can replace `-1 days` with any interval you want; you can read about allowed modifiers in [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) (shortly: `-N days`, `-N months`).

After removing unneeded data, you may want to issue `vacuum;` command which shrinks the database even further.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I knew I should have paid more attention in database class.

Comment: @whitequark, What do you mean by "shifted to the future"?

Answer (score 3):

(This is not an answer, but I'm leaving it up as a warning.)

I've seen two extensions that claim to do this in some way, but neither works.

- [Click2Clear History](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dckmogldcieahpaljopelnchhidcfhac) only deletes *recent* items. (Or tries to.)
- [History limiter](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dpdjaigdefdamkfcgjhbmpjbhiejjkph) deletes old items each time you visit the history.

However these (and I expect other extensions) only call
[`chrome.history.deleteRange`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html#method-deleteRange) — if you're lucky, with reasonable parameters. According to the documentation:

> Removes all items within the specified date range from the history. Pages will not be removed from the history unless all visits fall within the range.

And in practice, I can't see any effect, beyond (I think) pages not appearing in the history page. In particular the history database file is still large, and Chrome still makes a lot of IO to it. So I suspect (from *very* casual observation with Chromium 9 beta r68937) that `chrome.history.deleteRange` only affects what's visible in the `chrome://history` page and not what's stored on the disk and affects things like URL bar completion.

Comment: Both are bad news.  History limiter removes all but your last 7 days, so the moment you install it, you lose.  And Click2Clear History is a usability disaster, not to mention that the "custom period" in the screen shot appears not to work.  Avoid both these extensions---especially History Limiter, which irreversibly removes access to your history.  And it doesn't remove the damn data, either!!!!

Comment: What do you mean by that last line, 'it doesn't remove the damn data either'? I wanna get rid of the large History Index files on my drive, will it do that?

Comment: History limiter was fixed to not behave like Norman pointed out. Also, there is a fork of History limiter which seems updated and better: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-limiter-custom/ibpfkplbhnbiklpjacjbaelahebmbmpp/related

Comment: @bdombro damn it! I just lost all my history because of your inaccurate comment! 
It's not true that History Limiter (and its newer fork) were fixed to not behave like Norman pointed out... in fact **the second part of his comment where Norman said HL would irreversibly remove history** still holds 100% true, and what's even worst, this stupid tool will erase history **right after the day value is edited, without any warning at all!** I hope this will save someone else work at least!

Answer (score -1):

All these answers were helpful but outdated. I found and use the "History Limiter Custom" plugin and it works flawlessly.

History Limiter Custom is a newer version of "History Limiter" which has better performance and is mostly bug-free.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-limiter-custom/ibpfkplbhnbiklpjacjbaelahebmbmpp/related

Comment: BEWARE! This stupid tool will permanently erase browsing history right after the day value is edited, without any warning at all!

Comment: Do you mean that it deleted the history after you click “Set”?

Comment: exactly and when doing so it did not say that it was going to delete history permanently. Also "set" is not a synonym for delete, and one could think that the extension would just hide the old history rather than erasing it.

Comment: This is a good warning! I agree it should have a confirmation after clicking Set to delete stuff.